# How Much Abstract Algebra Do I Really Need to Know for Operator Theory/Algebras

Tags: soft-question, operator-theory, operator-algebras

My main interest has always been functional analysis but I've reached a wall where it feels like the next step to *really* understand it is going really deep into operator theory, which seems to rely heavily on algebraic concepts. I definitely want to expand my knowledge base in algebra for it's own sake but being able to do so in the context of functional analysis would be doubly awesome. Basically I want to know whether I could just crack open a text on operator theory and be able to understand it as an extension of the basic group-ring-vector space type constructions or would I be totally lost? If the former is the case, are there any good texts that do not presume an advanced understanding of abstract algebra?

Comment: I would agree with Martin's assessment.  Basic knowledge of things like category theory, group theory, representation theory, etc. can help to motivate a lot of topics, but that background isn't typically required.  You should be able to crack open a text without getting lost, given that you've seen some basic functional analysis (Banach spaces, duality, etc.).  For a text recommendation, it probably depends on what area you're interested in.  I've enjoyed Murphy's [text](https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/Textbooks/Murphy%20-%20C-Star%20Algebras%20&%20Operator%20Theory.pdf) on C*-algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, deep algebraic knowledge is a huge asset, but not a requirement.